# Using a MatInput element with @ViewChild the resulting variable is unavalable when running specs

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material

I have a search component in an old page and I am trying to write some tests for it, but it is giving my some grief

this is the template

```
<mat-form-field class="flex-row">
    <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
    <input #searchInput matInput placeholder="Search" type="text" [value]="search">
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="clear()" *ngIf="searchInput.value">
        <mat-icon>
            close
        </mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

The component uses the `MatInput` as a `@ViewChild`

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    searchUpdate: Subject<string> = new Subject();

    @ViewChild(MatInput, { static: true }) public searchInput: MatInput;

(...)

   clear(): void {
        this.searchInput.value = '';
        this.searchUpdate.next(this.searchInput.value);
    }

}
```

I am trying to test the `clear()` function:

```
it('should clear search', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.searchInput.value = 'test';
    spyOn(component.searchChanged, 'emit');
    component.clear();

    expect(component.searchChanged.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('');
}));
```

But I am getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

If I inspect the value of `component.searchInput` whilst running the test it is `undefined`

Why would the input variable not be available in the component scope for this test? Or What would be a better solution to test this?

Comment: Try calling detectChanges from ChangeDetectorRef inside our `it` before other code is executed.

Comment: The specs have the default `beforeEach` block which has the detect change in it.

Comment: Did you try `tick()` to advance the observable?

Comment: it fails on the first line, no need for the tick yet (i know it needs to be there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution was to change the query of the @Viewchild decorator to use the template id (`#searchInput`) of the input element:

```
@ViewChild('searchInput', { static: true }) public searchInput: MatInput;
```

Not too sure why the other query wouldn't work but this resolved my problem, so I am leaving the answer here for the community

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
it('should clear search', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spyOnSearch = spyOn(component.searchChanged, 'emit');
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        component.searchInput.value = 'test';
        component.clear();
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
           expect(spyOnSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('');
        });
    });
}));
```

Comment: Same error unfortunately, but thanks for the attempt. I didn't know the `whenStable()` method